# How can I match elements with different but similar names on different websites using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am scraping elements as Xml, from 3 different websites. They are have nearly same names or synonyms for example "warm-up type" and "heating type". In Turkish it is more similar "Isıtma Tipi" and "Isınma Tipi". And I have another problem about selects and inputs some of elements are select in website1 and textbox in website2 for example from Xml:

Room Count Selection:

```
<select name="Oda Sayısı">
    <option>Stüdyo</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1+1</option>
    <option>1.5+1</option>
    <option>2+0</option>
    <option>2+1</option>
    ....
</select>
```

And other website asks two seperate inputs

```
<input name="Oda Sayısı" type="text"/>
<input name="Salon Sayısı" type="text"/>
```

Additionally these inputs are changing category by category not all categories have same input.
How can I match them and merge into single element.

I am here for brainstorming I tried Damerau–Levenshtein Algorithm

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is far too broad to be answerable. The Q&A format of this site requires questions focus on a single problem with enough details to create a [repro]. Asking for general feedback or "brainstorming" is universally not supported in any of the StackExchange communities. The [help/on-topic] has more information about the topics we support.